# Saving author of form Web2Py

Tags: python, database, web2py

How can I save & display the name of the user who submits a form saved in a database.

For example:

I have a form that allows users to review products.
I then have a table that lists these reviews.
On the table I want to list each users name besides each review.

Comment: I don't know anything about web2py, but presumably you can save the submitter's name to your database the same way you saved the review text. Or is your question "how do I determine the name of the person using my form?"? I don't think that's something you can extract from their user agent or anything - you'll have to have an input field for it.

Comment: Yes that's what I'm aiming at, can I automatically save the user name into the review database alongside their review. Without them having to input themselves. I.e pre-populate a user field with their details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a reference field pointing to the `db.auth_user` table (or whatever table in which you store user data):

```
db.define_table('review',
    ...,
    Field('reviewer', 'reference auth_user', default=auth.user_id, writable=False),
    ...)
```

With the above code, the default value for the "reviewer" field is the ID of the currently logged in user. The field is not writable, so the user has no way to change that (in the review entry form, you might also want to set its `readable` attribute to `False`, as there is no need for the author to see it).

Then to display the reviewer name along with the review, you could either do a [join](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer#Inner-joins) or use a [recursive select](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer#Recursive-selects) (the former is more efficient if you are displaying many reviews at once, as the recursive select approach requires a separate database query to get each review's author).